# How do you put space in between parts of the website?

Tags: html, web, web-testing

Hello I was making a website for a friend and for some reason when you run it doesn't show space in between it. If you run it in HTML it shows a space but if you go to the website he published it doesn't show that. The website he published it on is: https://xploit.gq/ . Does anyone have a fix for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="generator" content="Mobirise v5.1.4, mobirise.com">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/logo5.png" type="image/x-icon">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons2/mobirise2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css">
      <link rel="preload" as="style" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <section class="header19 cid-scBqiokqjK mbr-fullscreen" id="header19-0">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="media-container">
               <div class="col-md-12 align-center">
                  <h1 class="mbr-section-title mbr-white mbr-bold mbr-fonts-style mb-3 display-1">Xploits</h1>
                  <p class="mbr-text mbr-white mbr-fonts-style display-7">Roblox exploits at its finest.</p>
                  <div class="mbr-section-btn align-center"><a class="btn btn-primary display-4" href="#bottom">Learn More</a></div>
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="card-wrapper">
                           <div class="card-box align-center">
                              <span class="mbr-iconfont mobi-mbri-code mobi-mbri"></span>
                              <h4 class="card-title align-center mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-7">Coded precisely&nbsp;</h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="card-wrapper">
                           <div class="card-box align-center">
                              <span class="mbr-iconfont mobi-mbri-cash mobi-mbri"></span>
                              <h4 class="card-title align-center mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>It's free!</strong></h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="card-wrapper">
                           <div class="card-box align-center">
                              <span class="mbr-iconfont mobi-mbri-key mobi-mbri"></span>
                              <h4 class="card-title align-center mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>No key system</strong></h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="card-wrapper">
                           <div class="card-box align-center">
                              <span class="mbr-iconfont mobi-mbri-setting-3 mobi-mbri"></span>
                              <h4 class="card-title align-center mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>Customizable&nbsp;</strong></h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section class="gallery3 cid-scF2ip4wCo" id="gallery3-4">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="mbr-section-head">
               <h4 class="mbr-section-title mbr-fonts-style align-center mb-0 display-2">
                  <strong>Full-Width Gallery</strong>
               </h4>
               <h5 class="mbr-section-subtitle mbr-fonts-style align-center mb-0 mt-2 display-5">Images with Title and Text</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4">
               <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <div class="item-wrapper">
                     <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features1.jpg">
                     </div>
                     <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                           <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                           Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <div class="item-wrapper">
                     <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features2.jpg">
                     </div>
                     <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                           <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                           Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <div class="item-wrapper">
                     <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features3.jpg">
                     </div>
                     <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                           <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                           Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <div class="item-wrapper">
                     <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features4.jpg" alt="" title="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                           <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                           Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section style="background-color: #fff; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; color:#aaa; font-size:12px; padding: 0; align-items: center; display: flex;">
         <a href="https://mobirise.site/g" style="flex: 1 1; height: 3rem; padding-left: 1rem;"></a>
         <p style="flex: 0 0 auto; margin:0; padding-right:1rem;">Mobirise site software - <a href="https://mobirise.site/n" style="color:#aaa;">Check this</a></p>
      </section>
      <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>  <script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script>  <script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  <script src="assets/smoothscroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>  <script src="assets/vimeoplayer/jquery.mb.vimeo_player.js"></script>  <script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to space to be displayed?

Comment: He wants it in between the code backround and the Full Width Gallery text

Comment: Here is the paste bin for the CSS https://pastebin.com/fzvpidbz

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want more padding between the code background and the text?

Comment: Yeah padding. I'm very sorry for the horrible formatting I'm very new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add some `padding-top` like so:

```
<section class="gallery3 cid-scF2ip4wCo" style="padding-top:10em" id="gallery3-4">
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="mbr-section-head">
            <h4 class="mbr-section-title mbr-fonts-style align-center mb-0 display-2">
                <strong>Full-Width Gallery</strong></h4>
            <h5 class="mbr-section-subtitle mbr-fonts-style align-center mb-0 mt-2 display-5">Images with Title and Text</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                            Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                            Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                            Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item features-image сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/features4.jpg" alt="" title="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <h5 class="item-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>Card Title</strong>
                        </h5>
                        
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mt-3 display-7">
                            Card Text. You don't have to code to create a site with Mobirise Builder. <a href="#" class="text-primary">Read more..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

On the website, it produces the following result:

[image: Padding-Top Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot your a big help!

Comment: @EvanBurnett If this solves your problem, please consider accepting my answer!

Comment: Though it looks very weird if you show it without CSS how would I incorporate the CSS or could I add you on discord and send you the full folder of the CSS?

Comment: Would you like me to create a chat room for this?

Comment: sure! How do we do that?

Comment: Theoretically speaking if this thread gets long enough, we can transfer it to the chat. Unfortunately, I don't think you have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: I uploaded my website to a file sharing website! Here it is https://gofile.io/d/HDVoze